# Converting XML to JSON in Groovy

Tags: xml, json, groovy, converters

I wish to convert xml to JSON using groovy. I understand the specifics of conversion is dependent on my preferences, but could someone please recommend which libraries and methods I should be using and provide me with a little information on why/how to use them? I am using groovy as I have been told it is a very effective parser, so I am looking for libraries that will take advantage of this

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can do it all with basic Groovy:

```
// Given an XML string
def xml = '''<root>
            |    <node>Tim</node>
            |    <node>Tom</node>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()

// Parse it
def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

// Convert it to a Map containing a List of Maps
def jsonObject = [ root: parsed.node.collect {
  [ node: it.text() ]
} ]

// And dump it as Json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( jsonObject )

// Check it's what we expected
assert json.toString() == '{"root":[{"node":"Tim"},{"node":"Tom"}]}'
```

**HOWEVER**, you really need to think about certain things...

- How are you going to represent Attributes?
- Will your XML contain `<node>text<another>woo</another>text</node>` style markup?  If so, how are you going to handle that?
- CDATA? Comments? etc?

It's not a smooth 1:1 mapping between the two...  But for a given specific format of XML, it may be possible to come up with a given specific format of Json.

#### Update:

To get the names from the document (see comment), you can do:

```
def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): parsed.collect {
  [ (it.name()): it.text() ]
} ]
```

#### Update 2

You can add support for greater depth with:

```
// Given an XML string
def xml = '''<root>
            |    <node>Tim</node>
            |    <node>Tom</node>
            |    <node>
            |      <anotherNode>another</anotherNode>
            |    </node>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()

// Parse it
def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

// Deal with each node:
def handle
handle = { node ->
  if( node instanceof String ) {
      node
  }
  else {
      [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
  }
}
// Convert it to a Map containing a List of Maps
def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): parsed.collect { node ->
   [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
} ]

// And dump it as Json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( jsonObject )

// Check it's what we expected
assert json.toString() == '{"root":[{"node":["Tim"]},{"node":["Tom"]},{"node":[{"anotherNode":["another"]}]}]}'
```

Again, all the previous warnings still hold true (but should be heard a little louder at this point) ;-)

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I have one further question about your solution however.. When you defined jsonObject, you specified "root:" and "node:", is there a way for groovy to automatically specify these names without the need for assumption, by analysing the names of the xml attributes?

Comment: @TomHadkiss Updated answer to show how you could do this (but again, with a more complex xml document, things are going to get funky) ;-)

Comment: Apologies, google isn't providing me with any answers.. How would you recommend working with XML that goes deeper? For example, <root><node><anotherNode>another</anotherNode></node></root>

Comment: @TomHadkiss Updated, but again you should be hearing an alarm as we're getting to the end of the road with this sort of generic conversion

Answer (score 9):

This would do the job: http://www.json.org/java/

At the time of writing this answer, the jar is available on: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107

The following shows the usage.

---

Imports:

```
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.json.XML
```

---

Conversion:

```
static String convert(final String input) {
  int textIndent = 2
  JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(input)
  xmlJSONObj.toString(textIndent)
}
```

---

Related Spock tests to show certain scenarios that we need to watch out for:

```
void "If tag and content are available, the content is put into a content attribute"() {
  given:
  String xml1 = '''
  <tag attr1="value">
    hello
  </tag>
  '''
  and:
  String xml2 = '''
  <tag attr1="value" content="hello"></tag>
  '''
  and:
  String xml3 = '''
  <tag attr1="value" content="hello" />
  '''
  and:
  String json = '''
  {"tag": {
      "content": "hello",
      "attr1": "value"
  }}
  '''

  expect:
  StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(convert(xml1)) == StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(json)
  StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(convert(xml2)) == StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(json)
  StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(convert(xml3)) == StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(json)
}

void "The content attribute would be merged with the content as an array"() {
  given:
  String xml = '''
  <tag content="same as putting into the content"
       attr1="value">
    hello
  </tag>
  '''
  and:
  String json = '''
  {"tag": {
      "content": [
          "same as putting into the content",
          "hello"
      ],
      "attr1": "value"
  }}
  '''

  expect:
  StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(convert(xml)) == StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(json)
}

void "If no additional attributes, the content attribute would be omitted, and it creates array in array instead"() {
  given:
  String xml = '''
  <tag content="same as putting into the content" >
    hello
  </tag>
  '''
  and:
  String notExpected = '''
  {"tag": {[
          "same as putting into the content",
          "hello"
          ]}
  }
  '''
  String json = '''
  {"tag": [[
          "same as putting into the content",
          "hello"
          ]]
  }
  '''

  expect:
  StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(convert(xml)) != StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(notExpected)
  StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(convert(xml)) == StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(json)
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who still need to resolve this problem.

Comment: Super simple with few lines of codes.  It also handles XML attributes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the party, but the following code will convert any XML into a consistent JSON format:

```groovy
def toJsonBuilder(xml){
    def pojo = build(new XmlParser().parseText(xml))
    new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(pojo)
}
def build(node){
    if (node instanceof String){ 
        return // ignore strings...
    }
    def map = ['name': node.name()]
    if (!node.attributes().isEmpty()) {
        map.put('attributes', node.attributes().collectEntries{it})
    }
    if (!node.children().isEmpty() && !(node.children().get(0) instanceof String)) { 
        map.put('children', node.children().collect{build(it)}.findAll{it != null})
    } else if (node.text() != ''){
        map.put('value', node.text())
    }
    map
}
toJsonBuilder(xml1).toPrettyString()
```

Converts the XML...

```xml
<root>
    <node>Tim</node>
    <node>Tom</node>
</root>
```

Into...

```javascript
{
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "node",
            "value": "Tim"
        },
        {
            "name": "node",
            "value": "Tom"
        }
    ]
}
```

Feedback/improvements welcome!

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents.

The code is in idiomatic Groovy, discards any namespace left-overs in resulting JSON and also converts numbers and booleans to it's JSON conterparts:

```
def toObj( node ){
  if( node in String ) return node

  def res = node.attributes().collectEntries{ k, v ->
    if( k in QName ) k = k.localPart
    if( v ==~ /\d+/ ) v = v.toInteger()
    else if( v ==~ /\d*\.\d+/ ) v = v.toFloat()
    else if( v ==~ /true|false/ ) v = v.toBoolean() 
    [ k, v ]
  }

  res.name = node.name() in QName ? node.name().localPart : node.name()

  def children = node.children().findResults this.&toObj
  if( children ){
    if( 1 == children.size() && children.first() in String && children.first().trim() ) res.text = children.first()
    else res.children = children
  }

  res
}

def xxx = '''<root><node>Tim</node><node>Tom</node> </root>'''

def json = toObj new XmlParser().parseText( xxx )

JsonOutput.prettyPrint JsonOutput.toJson( json )
```

returns

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "node",
            "text": "Tim"
        },
        {
            "name": "node",
            "text": "Tom"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I utilised staxon to get complex XML to JSON with staxon.  This included elements with attributes.

The following has an example of converting xml to json.

https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Converting-XML-to-JSON