# grails groovy - convert xml to JSON

Tags: jquery, xml, json, grails, groovy

I read a lot  of post concerning the conversion xml to JSON but I didn't find a solution for my case.
I want to send to the client side a xml data converted to JSON then parse it with jquery.

**XML:**

```
<mode name="name" >
   <data dataname="STO" str="none">data</data>
   <file dataname="FO" str="none">file</file>
   <file dataname="STO" str="none">file</file>
   <file dataname="STO" str="none">file</file>
   <data dataname="FO" str="none">data</data>
   <data dataname="STO" str="none">data</data>
   <data dataname="FO" str="none">data</data>
</mode>
```

**Groovy:**

```
def xmlTest = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
def nodetest= xmlTest.mode.find {it.'@name' ==  'name'}

def jsonObject = [ mode: mode.collect {
[ (it.name()): it.text() ]
 } ]

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( jsonObject )

render(view: "myView", model: [json:json])
return
```

**JQUERY:**

```
var obj = $.parseJSON("${json}");
alert(obj);
```

I tried to use the solution described here:[Converting XML to JSON in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830248/converting-xml-to-json-in-groovy)
but I didn't get all the struct of my xml and in the client side I had an error:
"Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Not sure if you're still having issues? The following answer (on your source link), will handle converting any XML to JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830248/converting-xml-to-json-in-groovy/24647389#24647389

Answer (score 0):

dude! 
This is working fine , `'Groovy Console'` , but at least there is no **"unexpected identifier"** error ..

```
import groovy.json.*
def xml ='''<mode name="name" >
   <data dataname="STO" str="none">ABC</data>
   <file dataname="FO" str="none">DEF</file>
   <file dataname="STO" str="none">GHI</file>
   <file dataname="STO" str="none">JKL</file>
   <data dataname="FO" str="none">MNO</data>
   <data dataname="STO" str="none">PQR</data>
   <data dataname="FO" str="none">STV</data>
</mode>'''.stripMargin()

def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )
// Deal with each node:
def handle
handle = { mode ->
  if( mode instanceof String ) {
      mode
  }
  else {
      [ (mode.name()): mode.collect( handle ) ]
  }
}

// Convert it to a Map containing a List of Maps
def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): parsed.collect { mode ->
   [ (mode.name()): mode.collect( handle ) ]
} ]

// And dump it as Json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( jsonObject )

print json
```

output :

```
{"mode":[{"data":["ABC"]},{"file":["DEF"]},{"file":["GHI"]},{"file":["JKL"]}
,{"data":["MNO"]},{"data":["PQR"]},{"data":["STV"]}]}
```

Done! Thanks to [Tim here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830248/converting-xml-to-json-in-groovy) realy nice work!

Comment: in the ouput there is no dataname and str attributes, I should have them also.
And I still have **unexpected identifier** in the GSP view :(

Comment: @Jils you should have tweaked this code to handle your tags...dude this realy works for me try to past all the stack trace here ...

Comment: @danielad - Thanks for the post, I am looking something similar to this but little change in the format like ... 

    {"mode":[{"data":"ABC"},{"file":"DEF"},{"file":"GHI"},{"file":"JKL"}
,{"data":"MNO"},{"data":"PQR"},{"data":"STV"}]}