# How to convert an XML file to a JSON file

Tags: json, xml, bash

How do I save the extract data from my Linux directories to JSON? I tried saving it to an XML file already where, if I run the script, it will generate an XML file like "data.xml".

I don't know how to convert it to a JSON file.

This is my XML template inside my Bash script:

```
file=~/data.xml
  template=" <Data>\n\
  <date>%d</date>\n\
  <time>%d</time>\n\
  <age>%d</age>\n\
  <place>%s</place>\n\
  <name>%d<name>\n\</Data>\n"

  echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' >> $file
  echo '<List2>' >> $file
```

template

```
printf "$template" "$date"\
                    "$time"\
                    "$age"\
                    "$place"\
                    "$name"\$file   
#closing tag
echo '</List>' >> $file
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do the same for JSON instead of XML? `template='{"data":{"date":"%d" ...`

Comment: @Thilo:Great suggestion.

Comment: @Gen you already have your data available to you in template ($date, $time, etc...). Your only challenge is formatting output in json format. It is not uncommon to have a script that can output your data in multiple formats.

Comment: If you want to keep the XML generator, you can also look into converting the XML to JSON. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830248/converting-xml-to-json-in-groovy for a good example.

Comment: Generic XML to JSON may be a challenge, since XML data are all strings, and JSON as very few types. No easy way to tell if a token like '12345' is numeric or string. Other way around (JSON->XML) is easier, using a tool like `jq`. With schema possible to convert, but this is more work to setup

Answer (score 10):

[github.com/mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) supports this out of the box:

```
yq -p=xml -o=json file.xml
```

You can use jq like expression syntax to chop and change the data if required.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: How does this work with very large files - is there streaming option?

Comment: No sorry - it reads the entire document in memory

Comment: This did the trick for me. One minor problem I found, although it's probably not the fault of the tool itself, is that if I have an xml that like `<doc><item><child>A</child></item><item><child>A</child><child>B</child></item></doc>`, after converting to JSON the first item's `child` property will be just `"A"`, but the second will have `["A", "B"]`. It would be nice to somehow make this into an array at all times, but not really sure how this could be implemented/hinted to the tool.

Comment: Because XML doesn't have a standard way of differentiating between an array of one thing vs just one thing, there's isn't a way for yq to know that. That said, you can post-process the structure to put things into arrays where needed - see https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/xml#parse-xml-force-as-an-array for examples

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I got this error message:

% yq -p=xml -o=json burp.cdata.json 
jq: Unknown option -p=ml
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://jqlang.github.io/jq

Comment: @MarioVilas make sure you're using mikefarah's yq here: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [xmljson](https://pypi.org/project/xmljson/) lib, and code something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from xmljson import BadgerFish
from json import dumps

def xml_to_json(xml_string):
    bf = BadgerFish(dict_type=OrderedDict)
    return dumps(bf.data(fromstring(xml_string)))
```